# Are Ether price questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

This hasn't really come up, but where do we draw the line about price discussion? For example, [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/822/131) asks about the value of ether after the POS switch. This is not simply a "what will the price be" question, but it could lead to excessive speculation, and may be off-topic. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

No. It's subjective, primary opinion based, leads to discussions and finally... not really clear what he is asking.

Comment: I agree, I think we should steer as far as possible away from price speculation.

Comment: holy, what a flood of content. someone opened the doors.

Comment: Agreed. /r/ethtrader is a good home for all price discussion, and it should stay that way.